# Getting value of parent's attribute from a fetched result?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am able to fetch data through Core Data using a predicate such as:

```
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@ AND %K == %@", "appearsOn.offeredAt.name", self.courseName!, "appearsOn.teeColour", self.teeColourString!)
```

However, when I attempt to use the `parent.grandparent.attribute` notation thus....

```
    let courseName = leg.value(forKey: "isPlayedOn.offeredAt.name") as! String?
```

...my app crashes at run-time with the error:

> [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Leg is not
>   key value coding-compliant for the key "makesUp.name".'

Am I using this in a valid way to access the property of a parent and/or grandparent object that has been fetched from the database?

For more context...

My entity `Leg` is a child of `Scorecard`, and `Scorecard` is a child of `Course`.

`Leg` is *always* a child of `Scorecard` via the `isPlayedOn` relationship; and `Scorecard` is *always* a child of `Course` via the `offeredAt` relationship.

So, I am attempting to access the `name` attribute of the `Course` that `Leg` is the grandchild of by referencing `isPlayedOn.offeredAt.name` of `Leg`.

Comment: Try `value(forKeyPath:)` instead of `value(forKey:)`.

Comment: Thank you @pbasdf! That is exactly what I was looking for. I hadn't appreciated that `KeyPath` meant exactly what I was asking about.